# jasper report not working in java need help to resolve it?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

hi friends I have created a java project and also used jasper reports in that project to generate reports, when I package my java project to .exe installer the jasper reports is working fine, but when I deploy that exe installer in another system the jasper report is not working ie:jasper reports is invoking in my system but not in another systems, I know that I have to change my file path but I don't know how to give file path which is accepted in all the systems and jasper reports will be working fine in another system too.

my code is :

```
       try( InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication14\\src\\resources\\bil.jrxml")){
    String txt = jLabel1.getText();
    String t1=lb2.getText();
    String t2=lbl3.getText();
    Connection cn;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billing", "root", "");
    Map <String,Object> mp =new HashMap <String,Object>();
    mp.put("bj", txt);
    mp.put("hpy",t1);
    mp.put("li",t2);

   // URL urpo=getClass().getResource("/resources/bil.jrxml");
     JasperReport jasperReport;
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,mp, cn);
   // JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Desktop\\rep\\simple_report.pdf"); 

  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "bil.pdf");
   JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint); 


}
catch(Exception eey){
    eey.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(eey.getMessage());
}
```

kindly help me to resolve this problem thanks in adavance

Comment: I would guess that the path `C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Desktop\\report\\bil.jrxml` can't be found on the other systems.  You will need to bundle the `.jrxml` with the application in some way...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you build your application, you will need to ensure that the `.jrxml` file is included within the resulting .jar file.

In Netbeans and Eclipse, you should be able to drop the `.jrxml` file into the `src` directory and it should be bundled as part of the build process.

This means you will no longer be able to refer to the `.jrxml` as a file, but instead, you will need to treat it as a embedded resource...

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/report/relative/to/the/src/directory/bil.jrxml")) {
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
}
```

(Nb it still possible that the `JasperCompileManager` will throw exceptions you need to handle, but at least the `InputStream` will be closed properly)

What this means is, if you put the `bil.jrxml` report in the `src/resources` directory (for example), you would need to use the path `/resources/bil.jrxml`

Now, I will discourage you from compiling a `.jrxml` file at runtime, as it's not a short process and the reporting process can already take several seconds if not longer, so you won't want to keep your users waiting, instead, pre-compile them and use the resulting `.jasper` file instead, which you can load at runtime...

Comment: am getting the following error as i said as per your commment

no suitable method found for compileReport(URL)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to String)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(InputStream) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to InputStream)
    method JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperDesign) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URL cannot be converted to JasperDesign)

Comment: Yep, that's what you get for not consulting the API docs first. Update

Comment: omg!!! i know that i have to update my code, but am asking why your suggested code is not working am getting the error

Comment: hey am getting the malformed url exception omg!!! can u tell me wats wrong in my code
try( InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication14\\src\\resources\\bil.jrxml")){  
JasperReport jasperReport;
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,mp, cn);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "bil.pdf");
   JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);       
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

Comment: I don't know, have you updated your question with the code you are using?

Comment: hey i have updated my code in the question kindly check it am getting malformedurl exception

Comment: `C:\\Users\\Applebj\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication14\\src\\resources\\bil.jrxml` is not a valid resource path, as I said in my post, you should use a path at s relative to the `src` directory, for example `/resources/bil.jrxml` - Remember, the `src` directory (and the project directory for that matter) won't exist once deployed, you should never use any kind of absolute path

Comment: i have given the path as relative but still not working 
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/bil.jrxml")){
}
am getting the error as
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : bil_oss_1413187709735_849639

Comment: Well, the good news is, the report has been loaded and I assume compiled, but now you've got a problem with filling it...You'll need to back into the report and figure out why...

Comment: i have open my i report tool and i have manually checked there the report is working fine there,do u have idea wat's the error would be

Comment: Nope, for some reason, JasperReports has failed to execute the SQL statement for `bil_oss_1413187709735_849639`, you'll need to dig that out and debug it.  It's likely the the exception might contain more information...